# MiKTeX gets no connection with a server. This happened after a massive updating or crash at the beginning of July

Tags: miktex, updating

[image]

The updating procedure finished normally, but after that no more package updates are available. Please, provide any solution not involving reinstalling all from scratch.

Comment: check if one of the work arounds in https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/580
or https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/571 help (the one is for 32 bit, the other for 64 bit). If not add an issue at the miktex issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue:

1-Shut down MikTex  if it is opened

2-Open command prompt

3-Run

```
set MIKTEX_REMOTESERVICEOFKLT=https://api2.miktex.org/
```

4-Then, in the same command prompt, run

```
miktex-console
```

5-Now you can update MikTex

It works with me!

Hope it will for you as well

Comment: Thanks man! 
I guess I was doing or executing the command in a bad way. But now, It worked!

Comment: Welcome man. Actually, I faced this issue samiliarly. Initially it did not work. Then when I repeated it again, it works!